# Don't allow to save edits in the table untill the field will be populated in ArcGIS with pythonaddins

Tags: arcpy, editing, python-addin, extensions

I have a table and some fields there(OBJECTID, UN_ID, for example).Table is not empty. how to prevent an edit session from stopping or saving until  the field will be filled. 
I wrote an extension onStopEditing(). It displays a message that the field is empty.

And how to make the module does not complete the editing?

Any suggestions as I am new to this.

```py
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class Uniq_ID(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled=True
    def onStopEditing(self, save_changes):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table.name,['OBJECTID','UN_ID'],"UN_ID IS NULL") as cursor:
             for row in cursor:
                 pythonaddins.MessageBox("UN_ID cannot be NULL","Error Message")

        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table.name,['OBJECTID','UN_ID'],"len(UN_ID) <>9") as cursor:
             for row in cursor:
                 pythonaddins.MessageBox("UN_ID must have 9 symbols","Error Message")
    del mxd
    pass
```

Comment: Sounds like a dangerous approach you are taking, you always need an option to stop editing without creating a feature or partially completing an edit. Have you explored `beforeStopOperation(self)`?

Comment: @Hornbydd I need the users of database could not save table edits until they fill the field UN_ID . Thank you , I will explore beforeStopOperation. Sorry for my English )

Comment: Have you considered modifying the field definition in ArcGIS to set "Allow NULL values" to "No"?

Comment: @SonofaBeach I thought about this, my tables are not empty, and  ArcGis doesn't allow me to set this option.

Comment: If the option would suit you, you could create a new field that has the no-NULLs option set (will need a default value) and then copy (calculate) values from your old field.  Then delete the old field and rename the new field to what the old field was named.

Comment: @SonofaBeach I had this variant but the error was occured. Where or when can I set a default value?

Comment: When you define the field, there is an option for allowing null values and another option for a default value.

Comment: @SonofaBeach but the error still occures( "Failed to add the field to the table/feature class")